# Php Contactform with error messages dont trigger php script

Tags: php, forms, contact-form

I've made a index.php  for a simple contact form with some error messages. The script and the form are in the same index.php (tryed also external, didnt worked) now i wonder why this script dosnt worsks i dont get mails, i get no error messages and no proper errors from serverside i checked a few times if i made some mistakes in the variables but i cant find anyone. Hope for help here, any idea why it dont work ? maybe its possible the PHP script dosnt get activated (it is before the actual form in the index.php file)

first try on stackoverflow :)

Heres the **PHP** script

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$name = $_POST['name'];
$prename = $_POST['prename'];
$sex = $_POST['sex'];
$company = $_POST['company'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$from = 'Demo Contact Form';
$to = 'martin.niklaus@gmx.com';
$subject = 'Message from Contact form';

$body = 'From: $sex $prename $name\n Company: $company\n  E-Mail: $email\n Mobile: $mobile\n Message:\n $message';

// Check if name has been entered
if (!$_POST['name']) {
    $errName = 'Please enter your name';
}

// Check if prename has been entered
if (!$_POST['prename']) {
    $errPrename = 'Please enter your prename';
}

// Check if sex has been entered
if (!$_POST['sex']) {
    $errSex = 'Please choose your sex';
}

// Check if Companyname has been entered
if (!$_POST['company']) {
    $errCompany = 'Please enter your Companis name';
}


// Check if email has been entered and is valid
if (!$_POST['email'] || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $errEmail = 'Please enter a valid email address';
}

// Check if mobilenumber has been entered
if (!$_POST['mobile']) {
    $errMobile = 'Please enter your mobilenumber';
}

// Check if prename has been entered
if (!$_POST['prename']) {
    $errPrename = 'Please enter your prename';
}

//Check if message has been entered
if (!$_POST['message']) {
    $errMessage = 'Please enter your message';
}

// If there are no errors, send the email
if (!$errName && !$errPrename && !$errSex && !$errCompany && !$errEmail && !$errMessage && !$errMobile) {
    if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
        $result = '<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! I will be in touch</div>';
    } else {
        $result = '<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later</div>';
    }
}
}
```

and the **HTML** script

```
<div class="form-holder mg-bottom-50">
              <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="index.php" method="post">
                 <div class="col-md-6">
                    <label for="name">Name*</label>
                    <input id="name" name="name" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']); ?>"/>
        <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errName</p>";?>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-md-6">
                    <label for="prename">Prename*</label>
                    <input id="prename" name="prename" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['prename']); ?>"/>
        <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errPrename</p>";?>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-md-6">
                    <label>Sex*</label>
                    <div class="form-choose-type choose-type">
                       <span>
                       <input type="radio" checked="checked" id="male" name="sex" rel="Mr" value="Mr" />
                       <label class="active Mr" for="male">Mr.</label>
                       </span>
                       <span>
                       <input  type="radio"  id="female" name="sex" rel="Mr" value="Mrs" />
                       <label class="Mrs" for="female">Mrs.</label>
                       </span>
                       <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-md-6">
                    <label for="company">Company*</label>
                    <input id="company" name="company" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']); ?>"/>
        <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errName</p>";?>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-md-6">
                    <label for="email">E-mail*</label>
                    <input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']); ?>"/>
        <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errName</p>";?>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-md-6">
                    <label for="mobile">Mobile*</label>
                    <input id="mobile" name="mobile" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']); ?>"/>
        <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errName</p>";?>
                 </div>
                 <div class="clear"></div>
                 <div class="col-md-12 mg-bottom-50">
                    <label for="message">Message*</label>
                    <textarea id="message" name="message">
                    <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']);?>
                    </textarea>
                 </div>
                 <div class="col-md-12 actions">
                    <input class="black-button" name="commit" type="submit" value="Senden" />
                 </div>
              </form>
              <?php echo $result; ?>

              <div class="clear"></div>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Thanks for help :)

Comment: You start out with `if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {` but you call your "submit" button _commit_ `<input class="black-button" name="commit" type="submit" value="Senden" />` Change your first if clause to match the submit button's name.

Comment: thank you, that was a mistake, fixed it but still dont works any other ideas ?

Comment: Place `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);` at the top of your page and start doing some debugging, stating that "it doesn't work" doesn't tell me much.

Comment: i get a error like this for every error variables  Notice: Undefined variable: errName in /home/httpd/vhosts/martin-niklaus.ch/httpdocs/lcb/tabs/Contact/index.php on line 281

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue:**
Wrong email format, but the message wont display bcaz

```
<?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errName</p>";?>
```

instead of

```
<?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errEmail</p>";?>
```

Modified scripts below

**php**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {

$name    = $_POST['name'];
$prename = $_POST['prename'];
$sex     = $_POST['sex'];
$company = $_POST['company'];
$email   = $_POST['email'];
$mobile  = $_POST['mobile'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$from    = 'Demo Contact Form';
$to      = 'martin.niklaus@gmx.com';
$subject = 'Message from Contact form';

$body = 'From: $sex $prename $name\n Company: $company\n  E-Mail: $email\n Mobile: $mobile\n Message:\n $message';

// Check if name has been entered
if (!$_POST['name']) {
    $errName = 'Please enter your name';
}

// Check if prename has been entered
if (!$_POST['prename']) {
    $errPrename = 'Please enter your prename';
}

// Check if sex has been entered
if (!$_POST['sex']) {
    $errSex = 'Please choose your sex';
}

// Check if Companyname has been entered
if (!$_POST['company']) {
    $errCompany = 'Please enter your Companis name';
}

// Check if email has been entered and is valid
if (!$_POST['email'] || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $errEmail = 'Please enter a valid email address';
}

// Check if mobilenumber has been entered
if (!$_POST['mobile']) {
    $errMobile = 'Please enter your mobilenumber';
}

//Check if message has been entered
if (!$_POST['message']) {
    $errMessage = 'Please enter your message';
}

// If there are no errors, send the email
if (!isset($errName) && !isset($errPrename) && !isset($errSex) && !isset($errCompany) && !isset($errEmail) && !isset($errMessage) && !isset($errMobile)) {

    if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
        $result = '<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! I will be in touch</div>';
    } else {
        $result = '<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later</div>';
    }
}

}
?>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-holder mg-bottom-50">
          <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="index.php" method="post">
             <div class="col-md-6">
                <label for="name">Name*</label>
                <input id="name" name="name" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']); ?>"/>
    <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errName</p>";?>
             </div>
             <div class="col-md-6">
                <label for="prename">Prename*</label>
                <input id="prename" name="prename" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['prename']); ?>"/>
    <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errPrename</p>";?>
             </div>
             <div class="col-md-6">
                <label>Sex*</label>
                <div class="form-choose-type choose-type">
                   <span>
                   <input type="radio" checked="checked" id="male" name="sex" rel="Mr" value="Mr" />
                   <label class="active Mr" for="male">Mr.</label>
                   </span>
                   <span>
                   <input  type="radio"  id="female" name="sex" rel="Mr" value="Mrs" />
                   <label class="Mrs" for="female">Mrs.</label>
                   </span>
                   <div class="clear"></div>
                </div>
             </div>
             <div class="col-md-6">
                <label for="company">Company*</label>
                <input id="company" name="company" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']); ?>"/>
    <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errName</p>";?>
             </div>
             <div class="col-md-6">
                <label for="email">E-mail*</label>
                <input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']); ?>"/>
    <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errEmail</p>";?>
             </div>
             <div class="col-md-6">
                <label for="mobile">Mobile*</label>
                <input id="mobile" name="mobile" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']); ?>"/>
    <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errName</p>";?>
             </div>
             <div class="clear"></div>
             <div class="col-md-12 mg-bottom-50">
                <label for="message">Message*</label>
                <textarea id="message" name="message">
                <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']);?>
                </textarea>
             </div>
             <div class="col-md-12 actions">
                <input class="black-button" name="commit" type="submit" value="Senden" />
             </div>
          </form>
          <?php echo $result; ?>

          <div class="clear"></div>
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

**Small Note**

You need to make improvement of the error displaying part and retrieving POST variables inside the input.

Comment: thank you very much, i see where i made a mistake :) any tips for future questions ? so i dont get downvotes;)

Comment: After ask the question and if the answer is correct, you can accept the answer. If any comments or answers are useful, you can do upvote by click the small grey triangle arrow on the left side of comments and answers